# Operation Bloodhound "Side Mission" Progression

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I recently started playing my first ever CS:GO mission assignment.
Upon looking around at the available missions, I noticed most form a path that leads me to earn some stars, allowing me to rank up my Challenge Coin.
However, there are some missions that form a path to, seemingly nothing, as shown in the picture below.

[image: CSGO Missions]

**What is the point of completing these missions?**

Be it some extra bonus for completing them all, or simply for the extra experience points they give out, I'd like to know why they are there.

Comment: Well I haven't gotten around to the bloodhound one but the earlier ones had some paths that ended in stars and some that just ended in a random mission with a drop. I think it is just an extra chance to get the drops from the rarer collecions and the xp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming they're there for several reasons:

**People like objectives**

Give people something to do apart from playing the game mindlessly, and enjoyment rates shoot up.

**Experience points**

Each mission gives exp., so more missions = more exp.

**The challenge**

People are always up for a challenge. Bragging rights are a part of it as well. "Well, I did that mission, because it's harder, and even though I gain nothing by it, I'd like to show it off".

**Drops**

Owning the operation gives you two additional weekly drops, but completing missions does not enhance drops